# zend setDefaultNamespaces in the ini

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

how can I put this

Zend_Filter::setDefaultNamespaces(array('App_Filter'));

in the ini file ?

Thanks in advance.

Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

In your `application.ini` file, add

```
filterNamespaces.0 = "App_Filter"
```

then in your `Bootstrap` class

```
protected function _initFilterNamespaces()
{
    $namespaces = $this->getOption('filterNamespaces');
    Zend_Filter::setDefaultNamespaces($namespaces);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Phil but I've meant avoid code in the bootstrap e put the same logic in ini file. Like resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.App_Controller_Action_Helper = "App/Controller/Action/Helper" or resources.view.helperPath.App_View_Helper = "App/View/Helper/"

Comment: There's no difference other than the fact the helper paths are handled by built-in resource plugins